# VS Code not doing type checking on typescript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to convert an existing codebase from flowtype to typescript, but VS Code will not report type errors in `.ts` files as expected.

[image]

Running `tsc` works as expected:

[image]

- I installed `typescript` and `tslint` as npm `devDependencies`.
- I added a `<root>/tsconfig.json` file.
- I added a test file in `<root>/frontend/ts-example.ts` with types that should fail very badly.
- Tried adding `"typescript.validate.enable": true` to my `settings.json` but it complained that was an unsupported setting.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: May be you need this plugin https://github.com/jstwister/vscode-flow-ide

Comment: @bestinamir no. That's preposterous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welp, uh...

I had the "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" extension disabled in my workspace.

Yep, that'll do it...

In case anyone in the future is as stupid as I am, check: VS Code Extensions > Disabled.

Comment: Or in my case, i had typescript validation disabled in settings! Thanks for the reminder though.

Comment: oh my goodness... @SabbirAhmed I agree! Thanks alex for the reminder here. A few hours to find a checkbox... ug

Comment: I tried searching for it to install it but only got the nightly TypeScript builds extension in the results. probably because the extension I needed can't be installed as it's included with VS Code